# Is there an alternative client for Homebrew?

Tags: software-recommendation, homebrew

Lately I've found myself increasingly frustrated with how long it takes for the standard `brew` client tool to do anything. I understand its being written in Ruby is the cause of most of its inefficiency. Are there any alternatives to the standard client? Has anyone written an alternative client in a faster language like C or Go?

Comment: I have only noticed that `brew` is slow to perform `brew update`, and then only when it's been left unattended for an extended period of time. Are you seeing slowness in other areas?

Comment: @EzekielElin discussions of the speed of the tool are out of the scope of this question, but I've found the tool to be pretty slow to do just about anything. It's been that way for the near-decade I've been using it.

Comment: Why wouidl C or Go be faster?   What is the ruby client spending most of its time doing?

Comment: Personally don't find brew particularly slow.  But could be your install got somehow corrupted (have you tried `brew doctor`?). Maybe also try disabling the automatic updates - these can really slow things down. It can be disabled via `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE`. see https://superuser.com/questions/1209053/how-do-i-tell-homebrew-to-stop-running-brew-update-every-time-i-want-to-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there exist no other implementations of HomeBrew than the standard one.

I doubt that the main cause of any wait times is due to the fact that it is programmed in Ruby. Such a program does not "magically" become faster just by being implemented in C. It is of course fully possible for other implementations to be faster, however one could also fear that for example an implementation in C would be more prone to security bugs.

Comment: I think you'd have to do a study of what the ruby application is actually spending its time doing, before you'd have to make a claim that re-writing it in another language would be a significant speedup.  Much as I have zero use for Homebrew, it's much more important to be *correct* than fast.